# Where is my pasted input going?

Tags: ssh, clipboard

I am copying and pasting sequences of shell commands into my terminal emulator, and I am confused by the behaviour.

- When I paste the single line `ssh user@remote "echo foo"; echo baz` the computer does what I expect.  It runs the SSH command and then echoes something after I have finished my SSH session.
- When I paste the same thing as a multiple-line command, however, this does not happen.

  ```
  ssh user@remote "echo foo"
  echo baz
  ```

  I still get the SSH session, but the `echo baz` completely disappears.  No command is run.
- This seems to be something to do with SSH, at least. Because replacing SSH with something else yields the behaviour that I was actually expecting. 
  Both commands run when I paste this, for example:

  ```
  echo foo
  echo baz
  ```

So what is happening?  Where is the pasted input going?  Why is the echo command not executed by *anything*?  How is this related to SSH?

(By the way: I know of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> method, but sometimes, especially when using terminal emulators on Windows, this won't work out of the box.)

Comment: The conclusion that you have jumped to, upon which you have then based the question, is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean specifically, that I'm referring to `ssh` as the source of this behavior? It might be one of the cases, and since I didn't search for any other, I've decided to leave it as an example.
Or do you refer to "copy-pasting" instead of "evaluating pasted"?

Comment: You've jumped to the conclusion that stuff is not being pasted, and then asked why pasting breaks.  It is not actually the case in the first place that the input is not being pasted.  So this question is based upon a false assumption from the title onwards.  _Where is this pasted input going?_ is by far a better question.

Comment: There you go.  The answer to this is actually fairly straightforward,  Let's see whether anyone answers it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pasting this:

```
ssh user@host 'read foo; echo ">>$foo<<"'
echo bar
```

You will see `>>echo bar<<` as output from the `echo` on the server.

This means that `ssh` will eat the pasted data on its standard input, as if you had done

```
echo 'echo bar' | ssh user@host 'read foo; echo ">>$foo<<"'
```

The solution to this, apart from never pasting shell commands into the terminal to run them, is to use `ssh -n`, which will redirect `/dev/null` into `ssh`:

```
ssh -n user@host 'echo foo'
echo bar
```

---

Unfortunately I don't know the mechanics of pasting, so I can't say anything clever about *why* the pasted data ends up on the standard input stream of `ssh`, but I'm guessing it has to do with the stream being inherited from the interactive shell (which reads commands from standard input).

---

Using `ssh -n` is also the solution (or at least *a* solution) to the issue of

```
while read something; do
    ssh user@host 'somecommand'
done <inputfile
```

Here, the loop will only run once since `ssh` eats the data from `inputfile`.